# Master view full screen

Tags: xcode, fullscreen, master-detail

Occasionally in my iPad Master/Detail app the Master View slides into view at a full-screen width rather than its usual 320p width. This happens under ios 5 and 6 on iPads 1 and 2. When it happens the view functions normally and the Master view continually reappears at full screen width until the app is restarted. Table view cells are also stretched to full-screen and so they look strange. I have not been able to characterize this except that it may happen only after I have received a memory warning.

There is no place in my code where I try to change the width (or anything else) of the Master view. Has this been seen or reported? I've found no mention of it in my searches. Thx

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on iOS 5 on iPad 2. The master view starts full-screen, however, rotating the device to landscape and then back to portrait fixes the width. Have you found any solution/workaroud?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Interface Builder to create the views? If so try modifying "Autoresize subviews" attribute in the "Attributes Inspector" of the view